# Cannot init a class object - xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to IOS development. I wrote the implementation file following like this.

```
   @implementation Utils

   +(id)alloc
   {
         return [self instance];
   }

   +(Utils *)instance
   {

        static Utils *utils = nil;

        if (!utils) {
           utils = [self init];
        }

        return utils;
   }

  -(Utils *)init
  {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
           mConst = [Constants instance];
           mCONT_REGEXP = [mConst CONT_REGEXP];
       }
       return self;
   }
```

When i call

```
 [Utils instance];
```

I got the error following Like this:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[Utils<0xbff54> init]: cannot init a class object.'
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Your issue is  -(Utils *)init here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to create a shared singleton instance?

In that case, use the following snippet:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance;
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static Utils *sharedUtilsInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once( &onceToken, ^{
        sharedUtilsInstance = [[Utils alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedUtilsInstance;
}
```

It is better to call it "sharedInstance" so that it's more understandable the instance is shared.

Answer (score 0):

remove your following method

```
+(id)alloc
   {
         return [self instance];
   }
```

And write code as/....

```
   +(Utils *)instance
   {

        static Utils *utils = nil;

        if (!utils) {
           unit = [[unit alloc] init];
        }

        return utils;
   }
```